# How can I update image in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How to update image in this code?

this is the Web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\auth\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\auth\ServicesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\TournamentController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

 //Admin Middleware
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard']);
    Route::get('/alltournaments', [TournamentController::class, 'createview']);
    Route::get('/create', [TournamentController::class, 'create']);
    Route::post('/save-tournament', [TournamentController::class, 'saveTournament']); 
    Route::get('/edit-tournament/{id}', [TournamentController::class, 'editTournament']);
    Route::post('/update-tournament', [TournamentController::class, 'updateTournament']); 
    Route::get('delete-tournament/{id}', [TournamentController::class, 'deleteTournament']);
    Route::get('/manage', [TournamentController::class, 'manage']);
    
    
});
//User Middleware
Route::middleware(['auth', 'isUser'])->group(function () {
    
    
});

//Public Routes
Route::get('/', [TournamentController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/tournament/{id}', [TournamentController::class, 'singleTournament']);
```

And this is controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Tournament;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class TournamentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      $data = Tournament::latest()->get();
       foreach($data as $d){
         if($d->teamsize == 1){
             $d->teamsize = "Solo";
         }elseif($d->teamsize == 2){
             $d->teamsize = "Duo";
         }elseif($d->teamsize == 4){
             $d->teamsize = "Squad";
         }
     }
       return view('site.home', compact('data'));
    }


     public function createview(){
      $data = Tournament::latest()->get();
      foreach($data as $d){
         if($d->teamsize == 1){
             $d->teamsize = "Solo";
         }elseif($d->teamsize == 2){
             $d->teamsize = "Duo";
         }elseif($d->teamsize == 4){
             $d->teamsize = "Squad";
         }
     }
      return view('auth.createmain',compact('data'));
   }
   //manage view

   public function manage(){
      $data = Tournament::latest()->get();   
       return view('auth.manage', compact('data'));
    }

   //create view

   public function create(){
      return view('auth.create');
   }

   //Create

   public function saveTournament(Request $request ){
    $request->validate([
       'tournament_name'=> 'required',
       'teamsize'=> 'required',
       'check_in_period'=> 'required',
       'formate'=> 'required',
       'fee'=> 'required',
       'prize_pool'=> 'required',
       'overview'=> 'required',
       
       
    ]);
    $tournament_name =$request->tournament_name;
    $teamsize =$request->teamsize;
    $check_in_period =$request->check_in_period ;
    $formate =$request->formate;
    $fee =$request->fee;
    $prize_pool =$request->prize_pool;
    $overview =$request->overview;
    
    $tournament = new Tournament();

    $tournament->title = $tournament_name;
    $tournament->check_in_period = $check_in_period;
    $tournament->entry_fee = $fee;
    $tournament->formate = $formate;
    $tournament->overview = $overview;
    $tournament->teamsize = $teamsize;
    $tournament->prize_pool = $prize_pool;
    if($request->hasfile('thumnial'))
    {
        $file=$request->file('thumnial');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('images/thumnail/',$filename);
        $tournament->thumnail=$filename;
    }

    if($request->hasfile('banner'))
    {
        $file=$request->file('banner');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
        $file->move('images/banner/',$filename);
        $tournament->banner=$filename;
    }
   

    $tournament->save();
    return redirect()->to('admin/alltournaments')->with('success', 'Tournament Added');

   }  

   //create END

   public function editTournament($id){
      $data = Tournament:: where('id', '=', $id)->first();
      return view('auth.edit', compact('data'));
  }


  public function updateTournament(Request $request){
   $request->validate([
      'tournament_name'=> 'required',
      'teamsize'=> 'required',
      'check_in_period'=> 'required',
      'formate'=> 'required',
      'fee'=> 'required',
      'prize_pool'=> 'required',
      'overview'=> 'required',
      
   ]);
   $id =$request->id;
   $tournament_name =$request->tournament_name;
   $teamsize =$request->teamsize;
   $check_in_period =$request->check_in_period  ;
   $formate =$request->formate;
   $fee =$request->fee;
   $prize_pool =$request->prize_pool;
   $overview =$request->overview;
   
    

   Tournament::where('id' , '=', $id)->update([

      'title'=> $tournament_name,
      'teamsize'=>$teamsize,
      'check_in_period'=> $check_in_period,
      'formate'=>$formate,
      'entry_fee'=>$fee,
      'prize_pool'=>$prize_pool,
      'overview'=>$overview,

     ]);
     return redirect()->to('admin/alltournaments')->with('success', 'Tournament Edited');
  }
    

  //Delete 

  public function deleteTournament($id){
   Tournament::where('id' , '=', $id)->delete();
   return redirect()->to('admin/alltournaments')->with('success', 'Tournament Deleted');
  }
  

  //User View
  public function singleTournament($id){
   $data = Tournament:: where('id', '=', $id)->first();
   if($data->teamsize == 1){
      $data->teamsize = "Solo";
  }elseif($data->teamsize == 2){
      $data->teamsize = "Duo";
  }elseif($data->teamsize == 4){
      $data->teamsize = "Squad";
  }
   return view('site.tournament',compact('data'));
}
}
```

I need to update image

Comment: You already are, in that `$request->hasfile('banner')` style blocks. (You should read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads, though; those could be like 1-2 line blocks. No need to mess with `time()` and extensions, Laravel can do that for you.)

Comment: can you please guide me how can update these?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the image by only inserting this small code:

```
        if ($request->hasfile('banner')) {
            $file = $request->file('banner');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(public_path('images/banner'), $filename);

            $banner = $filename;
        }
```

Also, below i update your function:

```
    public function updateTournament(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'tournament_name' => 'required',
            'teamsize' => 'required',
            'check_in_period' => 'required',
            'formate' => 'required',
            'fee' => 'required',
            'prize_pool' => 'required',
            'overview' => 'required',

        ]);
        $id = $request->id;
        $tournament_name = $request->tournament_name;
        $teamsize = $request->teamsize;
        $check_in_period = $request->check_in_period;
        $formate = $request->formate;
        $fee = $request->fee;
        $prize_pool = $request->prize_pool;
        $overview = $request->overview;

        if ($request->hasfile('banner')) {
            $file = $request->file('banner');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(public_path('images/banner'), $filename);

            $banner = $filename;
            Tournament::where('id', $id)->update(['banner' => $banner]);

        }


        Tournament::where('id', $id)->update([

            'title' => $tournament_name,
            'teamsize' => $teamsize,
            'check_in_period' => $check_in_period,
            'formate' => $formate,
            'entry_fee' => $fee,
            'prize_pool' => $prize_pool,
            'overview' => $overview,
            
        ]);
        return redirect()->to('admin/alltournaments')->with('success', 'Tournament Edited');
    }
```

Comment: not working Undefined variable $banner

Comment: i edited the above answer. have you check it?

Comment: thank you its fixed. can you help me with this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75339006/20215140